# Expand vector with different extensions

Tags: r

I have a vector called `myvec` ( with more than 10000 items). I want to expand the vector with the extensions (`.GT`, `.AD`, `.DP`) in the corresponding order and get the `result`.

```
myvec<- c("Apple","Ball","Car")
```

result:

```
Apple.GT, Apple.AD, Apple.DP,  Ball.GT, Ball.AD, Ball.DP, Car.GT, Car.AD, Car.DP
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(myvec, v1, FUN  = paste0))
```

If we need to change the order

```
c(t(outer(myvec, v1, FUN  = paste0)))
#[1] "Apple.GT" "Apple.AD" "Apple.DP" "Ball.GT"  "Ball.AD"  "Ball.DP"  
#[7] "Car.GT"   "Car.AD"   "Car.DP"
```

---

Or a faster option would be `rep` with `paste`

```
paste0(rep(myvec, length(v1)), rep(v1, each = length(myvec)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <-c(".GT",".AD",".DP")
```